# SQLite Update same table with Select

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to update a table based on the values in the table already.

Player Fixture

```
PlayerFId
FixtureFId
Availability
SelectedPosition
```

I want to update all rows where the player id is the same and take the values from a previous fixture id.

Example data

```
PlayerFId Fixture FId Availability SelectedPosition
    1           1          N              2
    1           2          U              0
    2           1          A              3
    2           2          U              0
```

I want to update all the rows for FixtureFId 2 with the relevant PlayerFId data for FixtureId 1.

End Result

```
PlayerFId Fixture FId Availability SelectedPosition
        1           1          N              2
        1           2          N              2
        2           1          A              3
        2           2          N              3
```

I have tried using this SQL but it doesn't map the PlayerFId values correctly

```
UPDATE player_fixture 
SET 
    Availability = (SELECT Availability FROM player_fixture WHERE FixtureFId = 1), 
    SelectedPosition = (SELECT SelectedPosition FROM player_fixture WHERE FixtureFId = 1) 
WHERE FixtureFId = 2
```

Comment: Where is this part reflected in he query: "where the player id is the same"?

Comment: That's where I'm struggling, I'm guessing it needs to be a self join?

Comment: You can reference the outer table in the inner query, just use an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the player's ID in the `WHERE` clause of the subqueries so that the result correlates.

```
UPDATE player_fixture
       SET availability = (SELECT pf.availability
                                  FROM player_fixture pf
                                  WHERE pf.playerfid = player_fixture.playerfid
                                        AND pf.fixturefid = 1), 
           selectedposition = (SELECT pf.selectedposition
                                      FROM player_fixture pf
                                      WHERE pf.playerfid = player_fixture.playerfid
                                            AND pf.fixturefid = 1)
       WHERE fixturefid = 2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=f6c49b7b381d774328f0ff987d39200a)

Comment: This sets both columns to null.

Comment: @Cael Try setting the alias on the outer table reference not on the inner ones.

Comment: It works if adapted to your sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1fba9e78b3a2e721fc88e01fa3e607a4 Maybe there is no fixture with a one less ID in your real data? See my edit on how you can try to cover this.

Comment: I tried setting the FixtureFId to a specific value on the inner query e.g. 1.  Why does it have to be minus 1?

Comment: Problem is the fixture id's could be completely random and some previous fixtures with higher value FixtureFId.

Comment: @Carl: Then you need a column (or set of columns) that defines an order on the rows. Without such a column, there is no way to determine a previous fixture.

Comment: This value will be passed in. I know the value so I thought I could just do... AND pf.fixturefid = player_fixture.fixturefid = 1 (or whatever the id will be)

Comment: @Carl: If you need to specify the values you can of course replace `pf.playerfid = player_fixture.playerfid - 1` by `pf.playerfid = <your value>` (Replace `<your value>` with your value.) in the first query.

Comment: I still get the nulls though which I can't understand?

Comment: @Carl: Edit your question and post sample data with which the problem is reproducible.

Answer (score 5):

SQLite does not allow `join`s in updates.  But it does allow you to update multiple columns with a single subquery:

```
UPDATE player_fixture
       SET (availability, selectedposition) =
            (SELECT pf.availability, pf.selectedposition
             FROM player_fixture pf
             WHERE pf.playerfid = player_fixture.playerfid AND
                   pf.fixturefid = 1
            )
       WHERE fixturefid = 2;
```

Comment: @Carl . . . I'm surprised you accepted and then unaccepted this answer.